# Show that if $n > 4$, there are at least 2 distinct graphs with the same labeled degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

A labeled graph with n vertices has degree sequence [deg(v1), deg(v2),..., deg(vn)], where the order matters. Show that if $n > 4$, there are at least 2 distinct graphs with the same labeled degree sequence

My intuition is to think if there are vertices with the same degree, then I can change those two vertices to get distinct graphs, except when the two same degree vertices connect to the same vertices. In this way , suppose deg(v1) = deg(v2) and if v1, v2 both connect to at least 2 other vertices, v3, v4, then I can disconnect v1 & v3, v2 & v4 and connect v1 $ v2, v3 & v4 to get a distinct graph. Therefore, the only situation I need to solve if there are vertices with the same degree is that they all connect to a same vertex. And I dont know how to solve this situation and if all degrees of the vertices are different. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. For $n=5$, is this an example? 1st graph has edges $ab,ac,bc,ad,be$, 2nd has edges $ab,ac,bc,ae,bd$? Both have degree sequence $(3,3,2,1,1)$ but distinct as labeled graphs since one has $ad,be$ while t'other has $ae,bd$?

Comment: yes, that is two distinct graphs of the same degree sequence @Gerry Myerson

Comment: There are no degree sequences with all degrees distinct. There is always a repeated value, and this is easy to prove.

Comment: Now, it can't mean that for any degree sequence there are two distinct graphs with that degree sequence since, for example, there is only one graph with the degree sequence $(4,4,4,4,4)$ (I assume we are talking about *simple* graphs here, no loops, no multiple edges). And for the same reason, it can't mean that for any graph, there is a distinct graph with the same degree sequence; no graph distinct from the complete graph on five vertices has the same degree sequence as that complete graph. So I can only interpet it as saying that for each $n>4$ there exists a degree sequence (continued)

Comment: (continued) with two distinct graphs. Well, just start with the example in my earlier comment and attach whatever you like to the vertex $c$ and you'll have such an example by playing the same game with $ad,be$ and $ae,bd$.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that I still don't understand the question, as the graphs $ab,bc,cd$ and $ac,bc,bd$ have the same labeled degree sequence $(1,2,2,1)$, are distinct as labeled graphs (since one has $a$ adjacent to $b$ and the other doesn't) but they have only four vertices. So maybe we're asking for graphs that are non-isomorphic as unlabeled graphs (but share a degree sequence). Now there are no examples with four vertices, but with five vertices $ab,ac,ae,bd,cd$ and $ab,ac,ad,be,ce$ both have degree sequence $(3,2,2,2,1)$ and are not isomorphic.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comments, Ziqin?